# For loops clarity

Tags: python, for-loop

I have 2 different codes:

```
def bar(a):
    return [ x**3 for x in a ]
```

And

```
def cube(a):
    for x in a:
        return x**3
```

If I define bar(a) as ([1, 2, 3, 4]), my output will be [1, 8, 27, 64].
If I define cube(a) as ([1, 2, 3, 4]), my output is just 1.
Why is that? Are they not suppose to give out identical outputs? Doesn't "for x in a" mean for every x in a do the following iteration?

Comment: Your way of thinking is actually what a generator does, if you want to change that second return statement to a yield statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you `return` from the first iteration of the for loop in the second case.

In the first case, you use a list comprehension

```
def bar(a):
    return [ x**3 for x in a ]
```

where you build up a list of cubes and return that, while in the second case

```
def cube(a):
    for x in a:
        return x**3
```

you start iterating over the list, but return from the function in the first iteration itself.

An equivalent way using `for x in a` would be

```
def cube(a):
    final = []
    for x in a:
        final.append(x**3)
    return final
```

Answer (score 5):

Returning within a loop doesn't create a list, it simply returns one value, aborting the loop. Your first example works correctly because it is a list comprehension -- it creates a list and returns it.

Comment: So by just inserting a list as my variable(a) will not automatically return a list for my output.

Comment: @MichelTamer: Well, `a` may be a list (or something else iterable), but `x` will be a single value. You cube it and then return that value.

Answer (score 2):

An appropriate second version is actually:

```
def cube(a):
    li = []
    for x in a:
        li.append(x**3)
    return li
```

instead of what you have. You should return the list of items, your version will simply return the first output item in the loop.

A more compressed form:

```
cube = lambda a: [x**3 for x in a]
```

In fact, you could just use list comprehesions/generator syntax directly, if you are not using this more than once.